# Why does Angular reset the form value as an empty object, when I run setErrors or updateValueAndValidity inside a valueChanges/statusChanges?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

As from the title of the question, I have this reactive form:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['fulvio', [Validators.required ]],
      lastName: ['cosco', [Validators.required ]],
      email: ['ciao@cao.com', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(new RegExp(AppValidators.emailRegEx))]],
      password: ['ciaociA0', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), AppValidators.passwordLogin()]],
    });
    this.checkPwDependingOnNameChanges();
  }
```

that I set up into **ngOnInit**, then in **checkPwDependingOnNameChanges**:

```
private checkPwDependingOnNameChanges() {
    const pw = this.loginForm.get('password');
    this.subscribe = this.loginForm.get('firstName').statusChanges
    .pipe(delay(10))
    .subscribe(val => {
      this.loginForm.get('password').updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
```

without that **delay** Angular (I guess) set the **loginForm.value** to **{}**
Does anyone know why? or am I missing something?

Comment: I can’t see anything here that would cause that..?

Comment: @MikeOne neither do I o.O

Comment: How do you actually know it sets the form to empty..? Any other code in that component that manipulates that form?

Comment: @MikeOne there is nothing else that manipulates that form.
I've put a console.log(this.loginForm) inside that subscription

Comment: Hmm... truly no idea, sorry? Can’t see anything wrong really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I put `onlySelf: true` and works as expected:

example:

```
 this.viewEditAppForm.get('noteNew')?.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
```

Angular version 11.1.1